# BIND9 sends notify to slave only with also-notify

Tags: dns, domain, bind, domain-name, master

I have a problem that has been driving me crazy for three days!
I'm replacing my Authoritative DNS servers with new ones and then I'm resetting all BIND9 configurations again to do a bit more "fine tuning" given the replacement.

I have configured a MASTER server and two SLAVE servers, I have configured a zone to be used as a test with a domain (FQDN) that I usually use for tests, the problem is this:

- When I update the zone and reboot / reload bind, from the logs I see that notifications are sent correctly but the all slaves, they do not receive (also verified with tcpdump port 53: no out from master)

`Feb 12 20:42:13 svr-3 named[12957]: zone test.com/IN: sending notifies (serial 20210                                                                                          21201)`

- If I add instead the directive "also-notify {slave_ip_1; slave_ip_2;}; notifications are sent and received correctly (verified with tcpdump port 53 and with bind logs) and obviously the transfer process starts and ends correctly

At this point, I believe that it is a problem on some configuration of the MASTER that I have escaped or set incorrectly, since the slaves receive correctly; it would appear as if it is not reading the authoritative NS records.

I am attaching the configuration files, perhaps with your help, I can find the error (the file is to be completed, I stopped as soon as I encountered this problem)

named.conf.options

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

        // forwarders {
        //      0.0.0.0;
        // };

        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        dnssec-validation auto;

        listen-on { xxx; };
        listen-on-v6 { any; };

        //IP da utilizzare per le richieste in uscita di aggiornamento zone e il forward dei dynamic updates
        transfer-source xxx;

        //Abilito le notifiche
        notify yes;

        //Quale IP utilizzare per le notifiche in uscita
        notify-source xxx;

        //IP da notificare in aggiunta degli NS RR
//      also-notify { yyy; zzz;  };

        auth-nxdomain no;

        // hide version number from clients for security reasons.
        version "Not Available";

        // disable recursion on authoritative DNS server.
        recursion no;

        // enable the query log
        querylog yes;

        // disallow zone transfer
        allow-transfer { none; };

};
```

zone file

```
; BIND reverse data file for empty rfc1918 zone
;
; DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is used for multiple zones.
; Instead, copy it, edit named.conf, and use that copy.
;

$TTL    86400           ;TTL (1 Giorno)
$ORIGIN test.com.    ;Base Dominio

; Record Start of Authority (SOA)
@       IN      SOA     ns1.test.net. hostmaster.test.net. (
                       2021021201       ; Serial
                          21600         ; Refresh (6H)
                          10800         ; Retry (3H)
                         604800         ; Expire (1 Settimana)
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL (1 Settimana)
; Record A
@       10800   IN      A       123.345.678.123
www     10800   IN      A       123.345.678.123

; Record AAAA

; Record CNAME

; Record TXT

; Record SRV

; Record MX
@       3600    IN      MX      1       mail.test.net.
@       3600    IN      MX      10      mail2.test.net.

; Record NS
@       IN      NS      ns1.test.net.
@       IN      NS      ns2.test.net.
@       IN      NS      dns.otherdomain.it.
```

named.conf.local

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "test.com" {
      type master;
      file "/etc/bind/zones/db.test.com";
      allow-query { any; };
      allow-transfer { key keytest; };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to the point of putting into production the new machines for the management of the Authoritative DNS servers and at this point I was able to perform a more precise diagnosis.

The problem has been solved, I think it was due to the fact that in the transfer phase I registered the new GLUE records with the registrar, then I transferred all the zones to the new master server and at this point I reported the problem to you .

But I had not yet reported (with the registrar) the new DNS addresses, because obviously the machines were not yet complete with configurations; yesterday I proceeded to run a DNS UPDATE, then to make the new services functional and SURPRISE!

Now by disabling the "also-notify" function, the master server is able to send notifications to the slave machines.

I honestly did not think that bind was going to check which were the authoritative servers currently set up at the registrar, I thought that only the NS records set in the zone file were enough.

Thanks everyone for trying to help me with this problem, I hope this experience can be helpful.